# Command to delete all pods in all kubernetes namespaces

Tags: kubernetes

Upon looking at the docs, there is an API call to delete a single pod, but is there a way to delete *all* pods in all namespaces?

Answer (score 626, accepted):

There is no command to do exactly what you asked.

Here are some close matches.

**Be careful before running any of these commands.  Make sure you are connected to the right cluster, if you use multiple clusters.  Consider running. `kubectl config view` first.**

You can delete all the pods in a single namespace with this command:

```
kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=foo
```

You can also delete all deployments in namespace which will delete all pods attached with the deployments corresponding to the namespace

```
kubectl delete --all deployments --namespace=foo
```

You can delete all namespaces and every object in every namespace (but not un-namespaced objects, like nodes and some events) with this command:

```
kubectl delete --all namespaces
```

However, the latter command is probably not something you want to do, since it will delete things in the kube-system namespace, which will make your cluster not usable.

This command will delete all the namespaces except kube-system, which might be useful:

```
for each in $(kubectl get ns -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}" | grep -v kube-system);
do
  kubectl delete ns $each
done
```

Comment: With the current version of k8s, the command "kubectl delete --all namespaces" does not delete the system stuff anymore... It says e.g.: namespaces "default" is forbidden: this namespace may not be deleted

Comment: Does this delete the deployment or just the pods?

Comment: `kubectl delete pods --all --all-namespaces` seems to work sometimes (not sure what causes it to work in some environments and not in others). It works well from my bastion host but not from laptop. Both running debian and both running the same version of kubectl (cluster version 1.13)

Comment: @KaiWähner if I'm not mistaken the k8s system-related stuff are in the `kube-system` namespace. In the message example, I can see the `default` namespace. Is `kube-system` deleted with the command you have attached?

Comment: ```for each in``` very helpful

Comment: The regular namespace-delete command failed for me (the namespace contents were stuck in the "terminating" state forever), but this script fixed it: https://github.com/ctron/kill-kube-ns

Comment: I wish I could go back in time and verify if my Kubernetes was linked to a production server before I ran this. Something like `kubectl config view`. Perhaps we could add some sort of warning before the answer?

Comment: kube-system, kube-public and default will not be deleted with `kubectl delete --all namespaces`

Comment: @antoineMoPa added warning per your suggestion.

Comment: Or you can see the output of `kubectl config view | grep namespace` and based on the result of the namespace, you specify it in the `--namespace` option. An example of a `default` namespace would be: `kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=default`

Comment: does deleting a single namespace delete all the objects in that namespace?

Answer (score 147):

```
kubectl delete daemonsets,replicasets,services,deployments,pods,rc,ingress --all --all-namespaces
```

to get rid of them pesky replication controllers too.

Comment: This is wrong. This only deletes in the current namespace.

Comment: Add the -n flag, but sorry that's for one pod at a time and not all at once

Comment: You are missing `ing` to also delete ingresses

Comment: you might want to add "statefulset" as well ( if applicable ). Otherwise it will keep forking new pods even after you run above command!

Comment: Also remove `apiservice` else you end up with namespaces locked in the `Terminating` state because some apiserivces are attached to them. cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369247/namespace-stuck-as-terminating-how-i-removed-it?page=1&tab=createdasc#answer-58644787

Answer (score 82):

You can simply run

```
kubectl delete all --all --all-namespaces
```

- The first `all` means the common resource kinds (pods, replicasets, deployments,  ...)

  - `kubectl get all == kubectl get pods,rs,deployments, ...`
- The second `--all` means to select all resources of the selected kinds

---

Note that `all` does not include:

- non namespaced resourced (e.g., clusterrolebindings, clusterroles, ...)
- configmaps
- rolebindings
- roles
- secrets
- ...

---

In order to clean up perfectly,

- you could use other tools (e.g., Helm, Kustomize, ...)
- you could use a namespace.
- you could use labels when you create resources.

Comment: This is the perfect solution!

Comment: This is a super killer !

Comment: This answer should be voted! Works like a charm!

Comment: This is awesome. It also does not remove the default and kube-* namespaces!

Answer (score 17):

You just need `sed` to do this:

```
kubectl get pods --no-headers=true --all-namespaces |sed -r 's/(\S+)\s+(\S+).*/kubectl --namespace \1 delete pod \2/e'
```

Explains:

1. use command `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces` to get the list of all pods in all namespaces.
2. use `--no-headers=true` option to hide the headers.
3. use `s` command of `sed` to fetch the first two words, which represent `namespace` and `pod's name` respectively, then assemble the `delete` command using them.
4. the final `delete` command is just like:
   `kubectl --namespace kube-system delete pod heapster-eq3yw`.
5. use the `e` modifier of `s` command to execute the command assembled above, which will do the actual `delete` works.

To avoid delete pods in `kube-system` namespace, just need to add `grep -v kube-system` to exclude `kube-system` namespace before the `sed` command.

Comment: You can also just drop `--all-namespaces` if you don't want to delete pods in the `kube-system` namespace

Comment: What will be the command to delete only few pod?

Example:

I had spin 20 Pod and now wish to  keep just 1.

Comment: Your sed didn't work on the Mac, but it worked in principle.

Answer (score 6):

I tried commands from listed answers here but pods were stuck in terminating state.

I found below command to delete all pods from particular namespace if stuck in terminating state or you are not able to delete it then you can delete pods forcefully.

```
kubectl delete pods --all --grace-period=0 --force --namespace namespace
```

Hope it might be useful to someone.

Answer (score 5):

K8s completely works on the fundamental of the namespace. if you like to release all the resource related to specified namespace.

you can use the below mentioned :

```
kubectl delete namespace k8sdemo-app
```

Answer (score 5):

steps to delete pv:

1. delete all deployment and pods or resources related to that PV

   ```
    kubectl delete --all deployment -n namespace

    kubectl delete --all pod -n namespace
   ```
2. edit pv

   ```
    kubectl edit pv pv_name  -n namespace

    remove kubernetes.io/pv-protection
   ```
3. delete pv

   ```
    kubectl delete pv pv_name  -n namespace
   ```

Comment: What is a pv? Will be useful to add a abbreviation in the answer to make it more informative.

Answer (score 3):

Delete all PODs in all Namespace only (restart deployment)

```
 kubectl get pod -A -o yaml | kubectl delete -f -
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `kubectl delete pods -l dev-lead!=carisa` or what label you have.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a one-liner that can be extended with grep to filter by name.

```
kubectl get pods -o jsonpath="{.items[*].metadata.name}" | \
tr " " "\n" | \
xargs -i -P 0 kubectl delete pods {}
```

Comment: `kubectl get pods --selector=app="${DEPLOYMENT_NAME}" -o=jsonpath='{.items[*].metadata.name}'     | tr " " "\n"     | xargs -n 1 kubectl delete pod`

Answer (score 2):

```
kubectl delete po,ing,svc,pv,pvc,sc,ep,rc,deploy,replicaset,daemonset --all -A
```

Comment: Be careful! As [PV is not namespaced](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#resource-types) the above command will remove all PVs cluster-wide.

Answer (score 2):

*One line command to delete all pods in all namespaces.*

```
kubectl get ns -o=custom-columns=Namespace:.metadata.name --no-headers | xargs -n1 kubectl delete pods --all -n
```

Answer (score 2):

#Forcefully complete prune or delete. Assuming foo is our namespace

**kubectl delete --all pods --namespace=foo --force**

#To keep watch on their removal from the list

**watch kubectl get pods -n foo**

Answer (score 0):

If you already have pods which are recreated, think to delete all deployments first

```
kubectl delete -n *NAMESPACE deployment *DEPLOYMENT
```

Just replace the NAMSPACE and the DEPLOYMENT to corresponding ones, you can get all deployments information by the following command

```
kubectl get deployments --all-namespaces
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubectl bulk (bulk-action on krew) plugin may be useful for you, it gives you bulk operations on selected resources. This is the command for deleting pods

```
 ' kubectl bulk pods -n namespace delete '
```

You could check details in [this](https://github.com/emreodabas/kubectl-plugins/blob/master/README.md#kubectl-bulk-aka-bulk-action)

Answer (score 0):

I create a python code to delete all in namespace

delall.py

```
import json,sys,os;

obj=json.load(sys.stdin);
for item in obj["items"]:
        os.system("kubectl delete " + item["kind"] + "/" +item["metadata"]["name"] + " -n yournamespace")
```

and then

```
kubectl get all -n kong -o json | python delall.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple pod which are crashing or error and you want to delete them

kubectl delete pods --all -n  | gep

Answer (score 0):

It was hinted at above, but I just thought I would helpfully point out that the shortcut for "--all-namespaces" is "-A" that's with a capital A.  HTH somebody.  I've opened a PR to have this helpful hint added to the official Kubernetes Cheat Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete pods in all namespaces just to have them restarted and you are aware that some of them will be recreated, I like the following for loop:

```
for i in $(kubectl get pods -A | awk '{print $1}' | uniq | grep -V NAMESPACE); do kubectl delete --all pods -n $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have hpa, then scale down.