# Unable to update image of StatefulSet in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I recently evaluated Kubernetes with a simple test project and I was able to update image of StatefulSet with command like this:

```
kubectl set image statefulset/cloud-stateful-set cloud-stateful-container=ncccloud:v716
```

I'm now trying to get our real system to work in Kubernetes and the pods don't do anything when I try to update image, even though I'm using basically the same command.

It says:

> statefulset.apps "cloud-stateful-set" image updated

And `kubectl describe statefulset.apps/cloud-stateful-set` says:

> Image: ncccloud:v716"

But `kubectl describe pod cloud-stateful-set-0` and `kubectl describe pod cloud-stateful-set-1` say:

> "Image: ncccloud:latest"

The ncccloud:latest is an image which doesn't work:

```
$ kubectl get pods
NAME                               READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
cloud-stateful-set-0               0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   7          13m
cloud-stateful-set-1               0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   7          13m
mssql-deployment-6cd4ff766-pzz99   1/1       Running            1          55m
```

Another strange thing is that every time I try to apply the StatefulSet it says **configured** instead of **unchanged**.

```
$ kubectl apply -f k8s/cloud-stateful-set.yaml
statefulset.apps "cloud-stateful-set" configured
```

Here is my cloud-stateful-set.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: cloud-stateful-set
  labels:
    app: cloud
    group: service
spec:
  replicas: 2
#  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  serviceName: cloud-stateful-set
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: cloud
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: cloud
        group: service
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: cloud-stateful-container
          image: ncccloud:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          volumeMounts:
            - name: cloud-stateful-storage
              mountPath: /cloud-stateful-data
  volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
        name: cloud-stateful-storage
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 10Mi
```

Here is full output of `kubectl describe pod/cloud-stateful-set-1`:

```
Name:           cloud-stateful-set-1
Namespace:      default
Node:           docker-for-desktop/192.168.65.3
Start Time:     Tue, 02 Jul 2019 11:03:01 +0300
Labels:         app=cloud
                controller-revision-hash=cloud-stateful-set-5c9964c897
                group=service
                statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=cloud-stateful-set-1
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             10.1.0.20
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/cloud-stateful-set
Containers:
  cloud-stateful-container:
    Container ID:   docker://3ec26930c1a81caa39d5c5a16c4e25adf7584f90a71e0110c0b03ecb60dd9592
    Image:          ncccloud:latest
    Image ID:       docker://sha256:394427c40e964e34ca6c9db3ce1df1f8f6ce34c4ba8f3ab10e25da6e89678830
    Port:           80/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Waiting
      Reason:       CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:     Terminated
      Reason:       Error
      Exit Code:    139
      Started:      Tue, 02 Jul 2019 11:19:03 +0300
      Finished:     Tue, 02 Jul 2019 11:19:03 +0300
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  8
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /cloud-stateful-data from cloud-stateful-storage (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-gzxpx (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  Initialized    True
  Ready          False
  PodScheduled   True
Volumes:
  cloud-stateful-storage:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  cloud-stateful-storage-cloud-stateful-set-1
    ReadOnly:   false
  default-token-gzxpx:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-gzxpx
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       BestEffort
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age                From                         Message
  ----     ------                 ----               ----                         -------
  Normal   Scheduled              19m                default-scheduler            Successfully assigned cloud-stateful-set-1 to docker-for-desktop
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  19m                kubelet, docker-for-desktop  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "pvc-4c9e1796-9c9a-11e9-998f-00155d64fa03"
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  19m                kubelet, docker-for-desktop  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "default-token-gzxpx"
  Normal   Pulled                 17m (x5 over 19m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Container image "ncccloud:latest" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                17m (x5 over 19m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Created container
  Normal   Started                17m (x5 over 19m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Started container
  Warning  BackOff                4m (x70 over 19m)  kubelet, docker-for-desktop  Back-off restarting failed container
```

Here is full output of `kubectl describe statefulset.apps/cloud-stateful-set`:

```
Name:               cloud-stateful-set
Namespace:          default
CreationTimestamp:  Tue, 02 Jul 2019 11:02:59 +0300
Selector:           app=cloud
Labels:             app=cloud
                    group=service
Annotations:        kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration={"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app":"cloud","group":"service"},"name":"cloud-stateful-set","names...
Replicas:           2 desired | 2 total
Pods Status:        2 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed
Pod Template:
  Labels:  app=cloud
           group=service
  Containers:
   cloud-stateful-container:
    Image:        ncccloud:v716
    Port:         80/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /cloud-stateful-data from cloud-stateful-storage (rw)
  Volumes:  <none>
Volume Claims:
  Name:          cloud-stateful-storage
  StorageClass:
  Labels:        <none>
  Annotations:   <none>
  Capacity:      10Mi
  Access Modes:  [ReadWriteOnce]
Events:
  Type    Reason            Age   From                    Message
  ----    ------            ----  ----                    -------
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  25m   statefulset-controller  create Pod cloud-stateful-set-0 in StatefulSet cloud-stateful-set successful
  Normal  SuccessfulCreate  25m   statefulset-controller  create Pod cloud-stateful-set-1 in StatefulSet cloud-stateful-set successful
```

I'm using Docker Desktop on Windows, if it matters.

Comment: There's [a hint buried in the documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#forced-rollback) that you may need to manually `kubectl delete pod cloud-statefulset-0` to make things progress, though what you're doing isn't technically a rollback.

Comment: @DavidMaze I created an update script for my simple test project which first created a new docker image and then used `kubectl set image` to request the StatefulSet to use it. It worked multiple times without any issues. I'm confused why I now would be required to run `kubectl delete pod` too. I however tried it and it said `pod "cloud-stateful-set-0" deleted`, but `kubectl describe pod/cloud-stateful-set-0` still says: `Image: ncccloud:latest`.

Comment: The difference in your current state is that the previous rollout didn’t complete successfully (your pods are in CrashLoopBackOff state).

Answer (score 3):

in my case imagePullPolicy was set to Always already:

```
kubectl patch statefulset web --type='json' -p='[{"op": "replace", "path": "/spec/template/spec/containers/0/image", "value":"gcr.io/google_containers/nginx-slim:0.8"}]'
```

helped in my case, see k8s docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#rolling-update

Answer (score 1):

In the stateful set yaml, change

```sh
imagePullPolicy: Never
```

to

```sh
imagePullPolicy: Always
```

Comment: Yup. The `imagePullPolicy` specifies how to acquire the image to run the container. `always` means it will try to pull a new version every time a container starts.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced an almost identical issue. I'm using a StatefulSet for a singleton Pod. I had ImagePullPolicy already set to Always. The Pod got stuck in a Backoff loop and would not update with a new image.

It turned out that the image spec stuck in a loop was an image with tag "latest" which does not exist; the control plane was stuck in a ImagePullBackOff loop with error `rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image...`

It seems that a Pod in a ImagePullBackOff state needs to be deleted and recreated. I believe the same is true for Pods in CrashLoopBackoff state.

It also seems that the spec for the StatefulSet can be updated, while the Pod remains stuck in a Backoff loop and does not get updated. i.e. The StatefulSet spec and Pod spec do not match.

What resolved this condition for me was one of two solutions:

Delete and recreate the Pod (not preferred)

```
kubectl delete statefulset my-statefulset
kubectl apply -f my-statefulset.yml
```

(where my-statefulset.yml is the yaml spec for this Pod)

OR Scale Pod down to zero replicas and back up to one (preferred)

```
kubectl scale statefulset my-statefulset  --replicas=0 && \
kubectl scale statefulset my-statefulset  --replicas=1
```

Additionally, one can add `spec.podManagementPolicy: Parallel` when recreating the Pod. This policy allows the creation of a new pod without waiting for the deletion of the one that's stuck in CrashLoopBackoff. This is ultimately how I resolved future occurences of this problem.

See also:

- [Redeploy statefulset with CrashLoopBackOff status in kubernetes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612592/redeploy-statefulset-with-crashloopbackoff-status-in-kubernetes)
- [How to clear CrashLoopBackOff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35453704/how-to-clear-crashloopbackoff)