# Namespace stuck in Terminating state with one finalizer named kubernetes. Where can I find documentation about it?

Tags: kubernetes, namespaces

I have a Kubernetes namespace that is stuck on Terminating. I've read that it's probably due to finalizers. When I run `kubectl get namespace $NAMESPACE -o json` I get the following finalizer:

```
"finalizers": [
    "kubernetes"
]
```

I can't find any documentation on this finalizer. Is it a built-in Kubernetes finalizers or does it come from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1):

It's kubernetes built-in and is there to ensure all objects are deleted. Is there anything at all in the namespace?

The resolution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53661717/578582), although this can leave stranded resources

Read the last few comments on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60807#issuecomment-499562515)