# skaffold never manages to delete namespace

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, skaffold

I've been using Skaffold with Minikube for local development for a few years now and it works great. Recently, however, Skaffold seems unable to delete the parent namespace of all my app's k8s resources. It deletes everything else, but running `skaffold delete` or `kubectl delete ns $NAMESPACE` do not work either, nor does opening up the minikube dashboard and trying to delete via its UI.

I know the solution thanks to other Stack Overflow answers like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67700916/927039) (you remove the "kubernetes" finalizer from the namespace resource), but I'd like to know why this is happening and if there's anything I can do to stop it from occurring rather than hack around it after the fact. Is it perhaps some incompatibility between Skaffold and minikube? I keep both on the most recent version via homebrew.