# Is there a way to get Kubernetes namespace from Terminating phase to Active?

Tags: kubernetes, finalizer

I have a namespace that gets stuck when you try to delete it, because of finalizers. I'm thinking of a situation, when I accidentally delete it, but I don't want to lose all the objects with finalizers. Can I undo it while it stuck in `Terminating` phase?

I tried to create a namespace with the same name, but of course it doesn't allow you to do that.

Comment: Not really, no. If you don't want to lose the pods/resources with finalisers, don't delete the namespace otherwise you will. Here's how to unstick it: https://bobcares.com/blog/remove-kubernetes-namespace-stuck-in-terminating/  and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71537261/is-there-a-way-to-cancel-namespace-termination-in-kubernetes