# Kubernetes Namespace stuck in Terminating

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, amazon-eks

I want to delete namespace and all resources under it.

So i ran

```
% kubectl delete namespace observability
namespace "observability" deleted
```

but this command was stuck, when I checked the namespace status it was showing `Terminating`

```
$ kubectl get ns
NAME                STATUS        AGE
observability       Terminating   14h
odigos-system       Terminating   14h
```

Then I tried to delete it by steps mentioned [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cloud-private/3.2.0?topic=console-namespace-is-stuck-in-terminating-state)

This command didn't returned any result
`kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | xargs -n 1 kubectl get --show-kind --ignore-not-found -n observability` so kill it.

Then I tried **Manually delete a terminating namespace**

But following command return

```
% curl -k -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT --data-binary @tmp.json http://127.0.0.1:8001/api/v1/namespaces/observability/finalize
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "the object provided is unrecognized (must be of type Namespace): couldn't get version/kind; json parse error: invalid character 'a' looking for beginning of value (61706956657273696f6e3a2076310a6b696e643a204e616d657370616365 ...)",
  "reason": "BadRequest",
  "code": 400
}%
```

Here is the namespace definition

```
kubectl get ns observability -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2022-09-20T02:25:56Z"
  deletionTimestamp: "2022-09-20T15:04:26Z"
  labels:
    kubernetes.io/metadata.name: observability
    name: observability
  name: observability
  resourceVersion: "360388862"
  uid: 8cef9b90-af83-4584-b26e-8aa89212b80c
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-20T15:04:31Z"
    message: 'Discovery failed for some groups, 1 failing: unable to retrieve the
      complete list of server APIs: metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1: an error on the server
      ("Internal Server Error: \"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1?timeout=32s\": the server
      could not find the requested resource") has prevented the request from succeeding'
    reason: DiscoveryFailed
    status: "True"
    type: NamespaceDeletionDiscoveryFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-20T15:04:32Z"
    message: All legacy kube types successfully parsed
    reason: ParsedGroupVersions
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionGroupVersionParsingFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-20T15:05:43Z"
    message: All content successfully deleted, may be waiting on finalization
    reason: ContentDeleted
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceDeletionContentFailure
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-20T15:05:43Z"
    message: All content successfully removed
    reason: ContentRemoved
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceContentRemaining
  - lastTransitionTime: "2022-09-20T15:04:32Z"
    message: All content-preserving finalizers finished
    reason: ContentHasNoFinalizers
    status: "False"
    type: NamespaceFinalizersRemaining
  phase: Terminating
```

I crated these Namespaces following this https://medium.com/@edeNFed/how-to-build-an-end-to-end-open-source-observability-solution-on-kubernetes-c8725c016dd5

I am on following version

```
% kubectl version --short
Client Version: v1.23.6
Server Version: v1.22.12-eks-6d3986b
```

How can i fix  this ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Namespace "stuck" as Terminating, How I removed it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52369247/namespace-stuck-as-terminating-how-i-removed-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is something wrong with your metrics-server.  Check to see if its up and try to resolve that root cause
`kubectl -n kube-system get pods | grep metrics-server`.  See https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server for more info

Comment: I updated `metrics-server` to the latest and `Terminating` namespaces disappeared.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/60807#issuecomment-408599873) should answer your question.